# Lock Drop Down Cells and Enable Use - Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cells, lock

I would like a drop down list in a cell. I would like to lock the cell so it cannot be moved or altered but changes other than selecting from the drop down menu.

Comment: That will require VBA. Are you comfortable with that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not familiar with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible,

1-First make sure all cells are "locked"
[image: Select All Cells]
[image: Lock cells]

2-Then Unlock the cell B3

3-Create dropdown list on cell B3
[image: Create dropdown list]
[image: a b c dropdown list]

4- Put this formulas in cells B5, B6 and B7
=IF($B$3="a"; "Yes it is a"; "It is not a")
=IF($B$3="b"; "Yes it is b"; "It is not b")
=IF($B$3="c"; "Yes it is c"; "It is not c")

5- Protect the sheet
[image: Protect sheet]
Only click Ok in the next dialog (first and second item should be checked)

The final should appear like this
[image: Final result]

The user will be able to change B3 only from the dropdown list and B5, B6 and B7 will change accordingly. You can enhance this solution without using VBA. You may also need some others formulas like AND, OR, CHOUSE.

I hope this helped

Comment: I have also found these links:http://www.ion.icaew.com/itcounts/post/Protecting-Excel-spreadsheets--Unlock-v--Allow-Users-to-Edit-Ranges

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-75481b72-db8a-4267-8c43-042a5f2cd93a